# Alert rule pricing confusion

Tags: azure, billing, azure-billing-api, azure-alerts

I have created an alert rule using a custom log query. Whenever the threshold is met, an alert is sent out using the alert action. In the image, it shows that the monthly cost $1.50.

As per the Azure Monitor pricing, it mentions that the Alert rules are charge based on the type and the number of signals used. Since I am using a single log signal with a 5 min frequency; based on the definition, I should be charged $1.50/month

However, speaking to the MSFT sales associate, I was told I would be charged based on the frequency of query executions. This means that if my custom log query is executed 8640 times in a month, the price I would be paying is 8640 * $1.50 and not a flat fee of $1.50/month

I am very confused and had no luck with the MSFT Sales Specialist for over a week.

I hope someone can clarify this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own understanding is correct, the monthly cost should be around $1.50 in your case.

The [pricing doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/) is very clear about it(in the **Alert rules** section).

And you can also calculate it by using [Pricing Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/). The screenshot as below:

[image]